# Slow Erlang code to find Pythagorean triplets

Tags: performance, erlang

Why does this Erlang code take about one minute on my machine?

On Pascal something like this took less then second on my machine.

What I can do to speed it up?

```
-module(slow).
-export([slow/0]).

pyth(N) ->
    [{A, B, C} ||
        A <- lists:seq(1, N - 2),
        B <- lists:seq(A + 1, N - 1),
        C <- lists:seq(B + 1, N),
        A + B + C =< N,
        A * A + B * B == C * C].

slow() -> io:format("~p\n", [pyth(1000)]).
```

Comment: i think it is possible to generate triplets in linear time, just think how to limit lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang runs on a VM, so you will get better performance on such a pure arithmetic computation by compiling it into native code using HIPE.

From the command line:

```
erlc +native slow.erl
```

Or from the Erlang shell:

```
1> hipe:c(slow).
```

Or:

```
1> c(slow, [native]).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it runs for 6 seconds. But: 1. How can I precisely mark down needed time? 2. How to run it much faster, like in notVM languages?

Comment: For such a small piece of code, structured around one nested list comprehension I am not sure what kind of profiling to suggest. I can't think of any reasonable optimization that would make this algorithm run faster, either.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this code is the `lists:seq/2` calls which generates lists in memory which you then traverse. Since you have 3 such generations, you end up with a cartesian product of generating lists. In effect, the Garbage collector has a lot of work to do then.

A much faster approach is to write functions which does the traversal by tail-calling each other. This way, you should be able to run in no time. It won't be Pascal-fast, but it will answer in a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: Would you mind providing a code example of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answers from Stavros and Jesper, I decided to make some test of various implementation of this function. The results are shown at the end of the code, measured by the method: `timer:tc(test_pyth,testx,[N])`. I was surprised to see that the method 4 is slightly faster then the 3, and I was even more surprised to see that if I remove all the `when` guards it becomes a little slower.

The version from John is, in my opinion, a good compromise between code efficiency and coding effort (writing, reading, maintenance).

Re-reading the algorithm, I realize that I forgot to test the case `A + B + C =< N` (a differnet problem tha the one I intent to solve...), so I have tested much longer lists. the initial code can be optimized like this:

```
test2(M) ->
    [{A,B,C} || A <- lists:seq(1,M-2), B<- lists:seq(A+1,max(M-A-1,A)), C <- lists:seq(B+1,max(M-A-B,B)), A*A+B*B == C*C].
```

*[edit]*
I add 2 tests compliant with john algorithm

```
-module(test_pyth).


-export([test1/1,test2/1,test3/1,test4/1,test2b/1,test4b/1,test/0]).

test1(M)->
    Test = fun(i,i,i,i) -> [];(A,B,C,R) when A*A+B*B == C*C -> [{A,B,C}|R]; (_,_,_,R)->R end,
    L = fun(Max) ->
            A1 = 1,
            A2 = Max-2,                
            L1 = fun L1(A,R) when A > A2 -> R;             
                L1(A,R) ->
                    B2 = Max-1,
                    B1 = A+1,          
                        L2 = fun L2(B,Rb) when B > B2 -> Rb;    
                            L2(B,Rb) ->
                                C2 = Max,
                                C1 = B+1,    
                                L3 = fun L3(C,Rc) when C > C2 -> Rc;
                                        L3(C,Rc) -> L3(C+1,Test(A,B,C,Rc))          
                                end,                                 
                                L2(B+1,L3(C1,Rb))                    
                            end,                                      
                            L1(A+1,L2(B1,R))                          
                end,                                             
                L1(A1,[])                                        
    end,
    L(M).


test2(M) ->
    [{A,B,C} || A <- lists:seq(1,M-2), B<- lists:seq(A+1,M-1), C <- lists:seq(B+1,M), A*A+B*B == C*C].

test2b(M) ->
    [{A,B,C} || A <- lists:seq(1,M-2), B<- lists:seq(A+1,max(M-A-1,A)), C <- lists:seq(B+1,max(M-A-B,B)), A*A+B*B == C*C].

test3(M) -> loop(1,M-2,[]).

loop(A,A2,R) when A > A2 -> R;
loop(A,A2,R) -> loop(A+1,A2,loop(A,A+1,A2+1,R)).

loop(_A,B,B2,R) when B > B2 -> R;
loop(A,B,B2,R)-> loop(A,B+1,B2,loop(A,B,B+1,B2+1,R)).

loop(_A,_B,C,C2,R) when C > C2 -> R;
loop(A,B,C,C2,R) when A*A+B*B == C*C -> loop(A,B,C+1,C2,[{A,B,C}|R]);
loop(A,B,C,C2,R) -> loop(A,B,C+1,C2,R).

test4(M) -> loop4(1,M-2,[]).

loop4(A,A2,R) when A > A2 -> R;
loop4(A,A2,R) -> loop4(A+1,A2,loop4(A,A+1,A2+1,R)).

loop4(_A,B,B2,R) when B > B2 -> R;
loop4(A,B,B2,R) -> loop4(A,B+1,B2,loop4(A,B,B+1,B2+1,R)).

loop4(_A,_B,C,C2,R) when C > C2 -> R;
loop4(A,B,C,C2,R) -> 
    case A*A+B*B -C*C of 
        0 -> loop4(A,B,C+1,C2,[{A,B,C}|R]);
        _ ->loop4(A,B,C+1,C2,R)
    end.


test4b(M) -> loop4b(1,M-2,[],M).

loop4b(A,A2,R,_M) when A > A2 -> R;
loop4b(A,A2,R,M) -> loop4b(A+1,A2,loop4b(A,A+1,M-A-A,R,M),M).

loop4b(_A,B,B2,R,_M) when B > B2 -> R;
loop4b(A,B,B2,R,M) -> loop4b(A,B+1,B2,loop4b(A,B,B+1,M-A-B,R,M),M).

loop4b(_A,_B,C,C2,R,_M) when C > C2 -> R;
loop4b(A,B,C,C2,R,M) -> 
    case A*A+B*B -C*C of 
        0 -> loop4b(A,B,C+1,C2,[{A,B,C}|R],M);
        _ ->loop4b(A,B,C+1,C2,R,M)
    end.


run_all(V) ->
    L = [{_T1,R},{_T2,R},{_T3,R},{_T4,R},{_T5,R1},{_T6,R1}] = [run(T,V) || T <- [test1,test2,test3,test4,test2b,test4b]],
    [X || {X,_R} <- L].

run(T,V) ->
    {T1,V1} = timer:tc(?MODULE,T,[V]),
    {T1/1000000,lists:sort(V1)}.

test() ->
    T500 = run_all(500),
    T1000 = run_all(1000),
    io:format("%% testx(500)  -> 1: ~5.2f, 2: ~5.2f, 3: ~5.2f, 4: ~5.2f, 2b: ~5.2f, 4b: ~5.2f~n", T500),
    io:format("%% testx(1000) -> 1: ~5.2f, 2: ~5.2f, 3: ~5.2f, 4: ~5.2f, 2b: ~5.2f, 4b: ~5.2f~n", T1000).


%% non native compilation
%% testx(500)  -> 1:  3.63, 2:  2.19, 3:  2.07, 4:  2.01, 2b:  0.37, 4b:  0.33
%% testx(1000) -> 1: 29.61, 2: 17.64, 3: 16.55, 4: 16.00, 2b:  2.97, 4b:  2.66

%% native compilation
%% testx(500)  -> 1:  1.03, 2:  0.64, 3:  0.35, 4:  0.23, 2b:  0.11, 4b:  0.03
%% testx(1000) -> 1:  9.49, 2:  5.47, 3:  2.68, 4:  1.71, 2b:  0.91, 4b:  0.27
```